# How to check from which view controller we are coming from to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have one screen like `screen1vc` and `screen2vc`. Now i have one view controller called `commonvc`.

My doubt is. in both `screen1vc` and `screen2vc`  i will allow user to see the `commonvc` screen. But in the `viewdidload` or `viewdidapper` i need to check fom which viewcontroller user is coming.

like

```
if (screen1vc) 

{

}   else if (screen2vc){

}
```

How can i do please help me out.I am making push seague to move to `commonvc`

```
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(commonvc, animated: true)
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to check this in `commonvc`?
that from which this controller is create?

Comment: Why do you need to know? Your `commonvc` should not need to know which view controller displayed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an UIView extension and use it in your entire application.

```
extension UIView{
var parentViewController: UIViewController?{
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
        if parentResponder is UIViewController{
            return parentResponder as! UIViewController!
        }
    }
    return nil                                                      
   }                                                                 
}
```

And use it like this

```
if parentViewController?.isKind(of: screen1vc){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parent controller property in common VC. set it in the prepareFor segue method in the screen1vc and screen2vc with self.

Now, in commmonVC, just check

```
if ([parentController iskindOfClass: screen1vc]) 
{

}else if ([parentController iskindOfClass: screen2vc]){

}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSUInteger numberOfViewControllersOnStack = [self.navigationController.viewControllers count];
 UIViewController *parentViewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers[numberOfViewControllersOnStack - 2];

    if ([parentViewController isKindOfClass: screen1vc]){

    }else if ([parentViewController isKindOfClass: screen2vc]){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift, if you are in the navigationcontroller stack then

```
navigationcontroller.viewControllers[navigationcontroller.viewControllers.count - 2]
```

will give you the UIViewController object you need.

In case you are presenting the view controller then `self.presenting` will do the job for you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do by two ways

1.To getting previous one from navigationController viewControllers array by doing like below.

```
if let navController = self.navigationController, navController.viewControllers.count >= 2 {
     let viewController = navController.viewControllers[navController.viewControllers.count - 2]
}
```

2.The another way by creating string variable in commonVC & fill required values while pushing to viewController.You can do something like below

Create a variable in commonVC

```
 var isFrom:String = ""
```

assign value before pushing using commonVc object.

```
 commonvc.isFrom = "screen1VC"
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(commonvc, animated: true)
```

Now in commonVC

```
if (self.isFrom == "screen1VC") 

{

}   else if (self.isFrom == "screen2VC"){

}
```